# Taking data from mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql

I am new to programming. I am trying to make a software. But i have problem.

The problem is :
My software is school administration. So when i enter the student roll number in java i need to retrieve his information(name, age, etc) which i stored in mysql. But the code i entered always give the same information for whichever roll no i type. Please help

```
String LibraryCardNo = txtCard.getText();
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    String Job = "";
    String Age = "";
    String LibraryCard = "";

    try{
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/library?" + "user=root&password=ainkhalid"); 

    Statement s = con.createStatement();
    String query = "select * from application";
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);

    while(rs.next()){
        firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
        lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
        Job = rs.getString("job");
        Age = rs.getString("age");
        LibraryCard = rs.getString("LibraryCardNo");
    }

    rs.close();
    s.close();
    con.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        String msg = e.getMessage();  
System.out.println("The problem is :"+msg); 
    }

    txtLast.setText(lastName);
    txtFirst.setText(firstName);
    txtJob.setText(Job);
    txtAge.setText(Age);
```

Comment: "select * from application" should be something like: "select * from application where rollNumber = 787878";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are looping over the result, but only keeping a reference to the last ones

```
while(rs.next()){
    firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
    lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
    Job = rs.getString("job");
    Age = rs.getString("age");
    LibraryCard = rs.getString("LibraryCardNo");
}
```

The method `ResultSet#next()` returns `true` and moves its internal iterator as long as there is still data to read.

Try printing them right away or encapsulating all that data into a class, instantiating objects and adding them to a list, which you then print out.

```
public class Student {
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    String job = "";
    String age = "";
    String libraryCard = "";

    // getters, setters, and constructors
}
```

And then

```
List<Student> students = new LinkedList<>();
while(rs.next()){
    firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
    lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
    Job = rs.getString("job");
    Age = rs.getString("age");
    LibraryCard = rs.getString("LibraryCardNo");
    Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, Job, Age, LibraryCard);
    students.add(student);
}
// display them accordingly
```

Consider reading [this official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

---

Obviously, if you only want to retrieve one row from the database, you'll have to switch up your query. Something like

```
    String query = "select * from application where roll = ?";
```

Use `PreparedStatement` and set values for the `?` placeholder.